# RedShift: How to cast integer with year into a date?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Assume a user tries to cast a number (year of birth) into a date.

```
select year_of_birth, cast(year_of_birth as date) from visit_occurrence
```

And gets this error :

```
cannot cast type smallint to date
```

What is the proper way?
e.g., cast(cast(YOB as string)+'-01-01' as date) does not work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
select year_of_birth, to_date(cast(year_of_birth as text), 'YYYY') from visit_occurrence ;
```